# Scala - can I ensure ??? is never called in my release build?

Tags: scalac

Is there a compiler (or static source analysis) flag I can set that will warn when `???` wasn't completely elided?

I wanted to use `@deprecated` for this, but the compiler rightfully complains when overriding a concrete method.

Comment: Why not remove the function and see if it compiles? Also, most IDEs have a `usage` test

Comment: @Dotan `???` is a built-in isn't it?

Comment: yeah, but it was meant exactly for the purpose of compiling the code before implementing the method. If you want to make sure a function isn't called it should probably not exist. Otherwise, use the IDE to check for usages

Comment: Clarification on the use case:  I need to implement a trait with an abstract method, but I expect that my method override will (ought) not be called.